# How do you write special characters ("\n","\b",...) to a file in Python?

Tags: python, latex

I'm using Python to process some plain text into LaTeX, so I need to be able to write things like `\begin{enumerate}` or `\newcommand` to a file.  When Python writes this to a file, though, it interprets `\b` and `\n` as special characters.

How do I get Python to write `\newcommand` to a file, instead of writing `ewcommand` on a new line?

The code is something like this ...

```
with open(fileout,'w',encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    fout.write("\begin{enumerate}[1.]\n")
```

Python 3, Mac OS 10.5 PPC

Comment: It's extremely important to note that it's not "when Python writes this to a file", it's "when Python parses a string literal from source code". You can read \b and \n from other files, user console input, network sources, carrier pigeons, whatever, and they won't be interpreted as control characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One solution is to escape the escape character (`\`). This will result in a literal backslash before the `b` character instead of escaping `b`:

```
with open(fileout,'w',encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    fout.write("\\begin{enumerate}[1.]\n")
```

This will be written to the file as

```
\begin{enumerate}[1.]<newline>
```

(I assume that the `\n` at the end is an intentional newline. If not, use double-escaping here as well: `\\n`.)

Comment: Thanks, works great.  I'm surprised I missed this on google :\

Answer (score 10):

You just need to double the backslash:  `\\n`, `\\b`.  This will escape the backslash.  You can also put the `r` prefix in front of your string:  `r'\begin'`.  As detailed [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), this will prevent substitutions.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use raw strings:

```
with open(fileout,'w',encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    fout.write(r"\begin{enumerate}[1.]\n")
```

Note the 'r' before \begin

Comment: wasn't the \n supposed to be escaped? oh, well.. print >>fout, r"\begin{enumerate}[1.]"

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks -- I knew it must be something simple like that.